# Publishing getting failed at Committing Deployment phase

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am trying to publish one page from Tridion with Webservice deployer in Tomcat server. But it is getting failed at committing deployment phase. Could you please help me?

The error message:

> Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed, Unable to prepare
>   transaction: tcm:0-60-66560,
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Cannot open connection,
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Cannot open connection,
>   Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-60-66560,
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Cannot open connection,
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Cannot open connection

Answer (score 2):

In cd_storage_config.xml, I put encrypted password, which I replaced with the normal password and it worked.

Comment: Encrypted password should work as well. `<Property Name="password" Value="encrypted:fhS6whp/g==hjS2G2rG6aI6T"/>`. You have to keep the 'encrypted:` also in the password, often I seen just the encrypted string only.